# Img src does not work on folders

Tags: html, image, src

How on Earth this small code does not work?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <img src="/logok/35_Facebook.png" alt="Smiley face" height="80" width="80"> 
</body>
</html>
```

If the image is in the same folder, it loads the image. If it is in the "logok" folder then it does not. I've tried: "logok/..." , "/logok/...", "logok//...." "logok/..." et.

**EDIT1:**
my html file is in a folder called "mdh", in this folder there is a "logok" folder, where the image is.

**EDIT2:**
I've also tried absolute path, it still does not work.

Comment: where your page is in directory reletive to path of .png?

Comment: `/` means start from root. `./` Start from current directory. `../` go 1 directory up. Maybe this helps.

Comment: Please show us your directory structure and confirm that you are testing using HTTP:// and note FILE://.

Comment: however the permission is forbidden if you try to acces the pic, maybe this is the problem :O

Comment: Try some different browsers, may be 403 error - Forbidden - Permission problem, try to change the permission using chmod a+rwx <filename>. If the problem still exists, it is strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yeah it was a permission problem, the folder had the permission to read but the files in it didn't
Thanks for your helps anyways

Answer (score 3):

Give the full path :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <img src="http://localhost/logok/35_Facebook.png" alt="Smiley face" height="80" width="80"> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: giving path like `E:\UploadedImages\1\crocodile.jpg` won't work?

Answer (score 0):

Your image is not loading because your path maybe wrong,Try to give full pathname

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <img src="http://www.mysite.com/logok/35_Facebook.png" alt="Smiley face" height="80" width="80"> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Only ever do this for cross domain images! There is no browser that does not support using / instead of a full domain url.

Comment: @RenéGeuze from op's question it is not clear about image folder path, so it is safe to give full path

Answer (score -1):

this works...

```
src="file:///C:/folder/img.xxx"
```